# python set subclass (list inheritance)

Tags: python, oop, inheritance

this is an example from Luts "Learning Python" on built-in classes extension with inheritance (section "newbies stucked"):

```
class Set(list):
        def __init__(self, value = []):
            list.__init__([])    #What is this for? when I removed this 
                                 #line nothing changed (question 1)
            self.concat(value)   

        def concat(self, value):
            for x in value:
                if not x in self:
                    self.append(x)
```

(question 2) Does list class have any attributes where it stores data? Could it be viewed as a Python code (I mean realization of list class)?

Please don't throw rocks) Thanks a lot for answers

Comment: The `list` class is a built-in and defined in C code. It doesn't set any publicly available attributes, no. The `list.__init__([])` line is indeed redundant, but still a good idea for future implementation changes.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Thank you